# How to use Select method of DataTable

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable, expression

Please tell me if i can use "Not Like" Operator in Select method of DataTable as filter expression?
I mean something like this:

```
MyDataTable.Select("MyField Not Like '" + MyValue + "%'");
```

Comment: did you try? did it work?

Comment: Should work if I read the documentation

Comment: -1 I've voted this question down because I'm pretty sure the most cursory of research will reveal the answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks EL Ronnoco, but i asked my questions after i did not find anything in my researches.i tried the above code but it did not work at the first.however i discovered that my problem is is in another place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this works.  For a list of all possible expressions see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx

Here also is a sample program demonstrating this works.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            // Create the first column.
            DataColumn textColumn = new DataColumn();
            textColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            textColumn.ColumnName = "text";

            // Create the second column.
            DataColumn priceColumn = new DataColumn();
            priceColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
            priceColumn.ColumnName = "price";
            priceColumn.DefaultValue = 50;

            // Add columns to DataTable.
            table.Columns.Add(textColumn);
            table.Columns.Add(priceColumn);

            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            row["text"] = "bc";
            table.Rows.Add(row);

            DataRow[] rows = table.Select("text not like 'a%'");
            Console.WriteLine(rows.Count());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this kind of expression????

```
filterexp = "fieldvalue!=value";
DataRow[] row = dt.Select(filterexp);
```

This may help you

Comment: Hi prema,Thanks for your reply.my expression now works successfully.your expression does not work for datatable select method.